# Average First Occurrence of Size n in Infinite List

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Lets say you have an infinite list $A$ that consists of 0s and 1s. The probability of a 0 occurring and 1 occurring is equal. The current element in the list gives no information about the next one. Now lets say you have a finite list $B$ of 0s and 1s with size $n$. What is the average index of the first occurrence of $B$ inside $A$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural starting point is work it out for $n=2$.  What's the answer for $B=00$?  What about $B=01$?

Comment: @lulu - your point presumably being that they are not the same

Comment: @Henry  Well, yes.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).